# get only the text from a link

Tags: php, explode

I have this method:

```
$message->from_address
```

Which when displayed on the browser, is displayed as

```
<a href="some text">asdasd</a>
```

I only need the text `asdasd`. How would I separate it such that the  `<a href="some text">` and `</a>` parts will be separated.

I want it that way because in order to be stored in a variable to be re-used later. I tried exploding it by having `>` as my delimiter but it only displays the full text. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = '<a href="some text">asdasd</a>';

echo strip_tags($str);
```